# Alias Trouble - I Lost my original Hotmail email name

Tags: outlook.com

I've had a Hotmail account for over 15 years that I use as my primary account. Today I was doing some house cleaning on all my email accts and I thought the alias account was something I'd use for security/recovery (stupid I know). So, what I ended up doing was removing all the alias', incl the original myname@hotmail.com, made one of my gmail accts my primary alias. Next thing I know I can't log into my Hotmail acct anymore with the original name, and it appears that I can't get email from that name either.

Everything I've read says go back to Alias and add it back, but when I try to add it back it won't let me do it and says, "This email is part of a reserved domain. Please enter a different email address"?

It lets me doing it under myname@outlook.com, but that also doesn't seem to get mail that is sent to my old Hotmail acct. I have over 1000 people who have that email address, and when I test from another acct it gives me a delivery status notification (failure).

I'm freaking out, did I just lose myname@hotmail.com for good, or is there a way I can get my account back to that name again?

Answer (score 2):

From what I've read [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/outlook/add-alias-account), and [here](http://www.emaildiscussions.com/showthread.php?t=68909), everything indicates that you can't add back your original myname@hotmail.com, or at least not right now, but you might have some options:

1. Wait for a rather longer amount of time, until the address is free and create a new account with it.  (Not a new alias because it won't let you.)  This period can vary from 30 days to 1 year.  The thing is that in the mean you'll have to let everyone know that your address is another one.
2. Pretend that you've been hacked and try to convince MSN costumer help to revert your account status to a date before the alias was deleted.  To do this, it's IMPORTANT to first BACK UP all your e-mail, contacts and calendar because there is also a chance that the account could get blocked permanently.  To back up all e-mail, I would move the mail on every folder (including Sent and Archived) to Inbox and then access the original account with Gmail or Thunderbird through POP.  You might need to create an alias ending in @outlook.com for your screwed up Microsoft account.
   It might be also a good idea to ask to revert the status of your account from a different IP location (as if your computer were compromised and had so many virus that it became a zoo...)

The second method is riskier but you'd be able to recover your myname@hotmail.com faster.

Let us know how everything turned out.

Comment: and also [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/oaccount-omyinfo/i-deleted-my-old-hotmail-alias-account/58a8b314-007a-4215-af53-6de91176386d)

Comment: [here](http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/162349-How-to-lose-OneDrive-data-and-subscription-with-Microsoft-s-help)

Comment: [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/oemail-osend/can-i-make-one-of-my-aliases-in-outlookcom-my/42eae317-cfbf-49e2-9e42-08c5edbd5a0d)

Comment: and finally [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/oemail-osend/can-i-make-one-of-my-aliases-in-outlookcom-my/42eae317-cfbf-49e2-9e42-08c5edbd5a0d)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, my @hotmail.com address was hacked and i was being blackmailed, this is the reason i removed it from alias so that the hackers would think my email was deleted. How wrong was i, it actually was deleted. I just thought this was a temp thing until i added it back. Anyhow, who do i contact to get this ball rolling to reinstate this addrfess again as this email address is well over 20 years old. And was my main email, i have no backups either. And i have some emails in there for evidence that i need urgently.

Comment: Welcome. Also check  [How to Answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) and [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers). I would also recommend editing your answer by adding your comments to your answer.